# Missing intellisence data tip for a datarow.item in VS 2012 and beyond

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Ever since I updated from VS 2010, I have lost the ability to get data tips from a datarow.item in my default Visual Basic programing environment. Just gone! I have put up with it, because what else does one do? After several searches I have found no answer. My debug life has lost a lot of quality by this apparent 'improvement'. Data tips are present as the image below shows, the issue is elswhere.

The image below is a composite of 4 different screen captures of the same code stoped in debug mode for purpose of checking the variable values. The only difference is the different (highlited in red) mouse hover positions.

Image part 1 and 2 show the variables with their values, this is to prove that both the datagrid.row and the findrow.row are in scope!

Image part 3 shows the mouse hovering over the value of the RowG.cell and clearly shows the value of that cell.

Image part 4 shows the ONLY intellisense available for the datarow which is to show the datarow, from there I can expose the item Array and see the values of all the items. However hovering the mouse over the 'item' or the '.tostring' produces no further intellisense data tip.

The exact same data tip available for the grid values WAS available for the datarow.item in VS 2010 and 2008 and 2005 !!!! Since 2012 version the only available intellisense is to expose the item array and go through the rows remembering what column numbers correspond with what names in order to inconveniently spot check an items value.

The question is WHERE IS my datarow.item data tip hiding? Is there a specific setting I have not enabled? Or has this function dissapeared?

EDIT 1: A more important question for those reading this, are you able to replicate the data tip issue for datarow.item? **Even if the solution is not known to you, it would be nice to quantify if this is an issue isolated to me or few or all.** Please include the VS version you are using. I have already invested several hours in this question and would really appreciate some help.

[image: Missing data tip example]

EDIT 2: Test code as requested by Engerlost in comments.
Paste the following code into a new Win Form project replacing Form1_Load, then run project, this will adequately show the issue.

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'New data table
        Dim Test_Data_Table As New DataTable

        'Add one column
        Dim A() As DataColumn = {Test_Data_Table.Columns.Add("TestCol")}

        'Add row 1
        Dim dsNewRow As DataRow = Test_Data_Table.NewRow()
        dsNewRow.Item("TestCol") = "Row1"
        Test_Data_Table.Rows.Add(dsNewRow)

        'Add row 2
        dsNewRow = Test_Data_Table.NewRow()
        dsNewRow.Item("TestCol") = "Row2"
        Test_Data_Table.Rows.Add(dsNewRow)

        For Each row As DataRow In Test_Data_Table.Rows
            Dim ShowTestColContent = row.Item("TestCol").ToString
            Stop
            'On the stop, debug will have a 'Row1' value for ShowTestColContent variable
            'In VS 2010 and earlier hovering the mouse over the row.item produced a datatip with the value as well
            'Since VS 2012 only the row shows an intellisence of the datatrow item array but nothing else
        Next

    End Sub
```

EDIT 3:
Here is further prof of the issue, same code placed in a new winform app, one in VS 2010 SP1 and one in VS 2013 Update 4. Placing the cursor over the item in VS 2010 produces the data tip. In VS 2012 and 2013 this feature is MISSING and nothing is displayed. YET, as the first image shows, data tips are showing on the VS 2013 installation, for normal variables and also for a datagridview row. The problem is elsewhere! [image: VS 2010 showing datatip]

This was further supported by Engerlost in the comments.

Comment: I must admit Im frustrated, 22 view and  not one "yea I have it' or 'no I don't'. Makes me question what else can I do to make the Q. attractive enough to warrant an answer or a comment as well as if Im perhaps the only one in the world that looks at debug info this way? I am a hobby programer and don't have access to others in the industry outside of the forum to compare VS installations.

Comment: A long time without using `datagridview` but that is a normal or I just never payed too much attention. Are you using `Option Explicit` ? I have both vs10 and vs13 installed. If you can provided a working example I can debug myself.

Comment: Yes Option Explicit is on, turning it off make no difference, however as I said the same program showed the datatable.row.item data tips in VS2010 then after transfer to 2012 and 2014 they are gone. its not about the datagridview I showed that as an example of what used to happen in VS2010 and earlier with datarow.item. I can create some code to quick test this. Thanks

Comment: Added sample code to be placed into VS Winform project, thank you.

Comment: Thanks!. I try on both versions. 2013 won't show the value when hovering over `item` as 2010 did. Been looking for an option but no luck whatsoever.

Comment: No, THANK YOU, for testing and for verifying the problem. I have posted an image showing the same. This may be a problem that is not just my installation. A few others to verify would be great.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2008 Professional on Windows XP I get a tip on `ShowTestColContent`, but nothing on the rest of the line.

Comment: Thanks Justin appreciate the time taken to run the test. Makes it that much harder to diagnose issues when those data tips are missing.

Comment: This is SOOOOOO frustrating. With a large table looking for the value constitutes finding the table column list and then looking at the value in the array. LOL its like what it must have been in the dark ages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm this behaviour on VS 2010 and VS 2013. When hovering `item` while debugging con 2010 it displays both property info and value. Propery is on the left and value (text visualizer) on the right.

Hovewer, on VS 2013 hovering over `item` shows nothing but hovering on `row.` gives the property info.

Finally on both versions `ShowTestColContent` shows the value `"Row1"`

> Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate
>
> Version: 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel

And

> Visual Studio 2013 Community
>
> Version: 12.0.31101.00 Update 4

New test on:

> Visual Studio 2015 Community
>
> Version: 14.0.23107.0 D14REL

I've tried differents debug/compile options but nothing seems to be working. The images I can upload are the same as OP.

**Edit on 4/3/2016**

Well, I think it's fixed.

Vainilla VS 2015 Community Update 2 (14.0.25123.00)

[image: VS2015UP2]

Cursor is where the black line is (over item).

Couldn't test on 2015 Update 1 though.

Comment: Thanks for your help. this is now a bug in the MS system so hopefully this will be rectified for VS users everywhere.

Comment: Unfortunately the release of 2013 Update 5 still has no correction

Comment: @user1500403 Just tried VS 2015 and nothing shows up :(

Comment: @user1500403 See my edit. I'd forget about remote desktop! Just tried it, seems to be fixed!

Comment: Thanks for that ! I hope that they will do an update for VS 2013 that has this, most of my work is with datatables and data.

Answer (score 0):

Finally some movement from a post on a MS blog I made a few days ago , the above IS a VS issue, undiscovered since release of VS 2012.

@Mike, thanks for reporting the issue with hovering on data row items.  This had not been previously reported so is still an issue in the RC release of 2015.  The root cause is in code that is part of the Roslyn open source project, so you can follow the status of the issue we created to track this at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/2602

Comment: We'll have to wait then :)

Comment: engerlost please place your findings from the comments above as an answer so I can accept it as the bounty recipient since there is no answer posible and you were the first to post Im happy to give you the points.